# MySQL find replace only the number as a whole

Tags: mysql

If I use

```
UPDATE oc_product_option_value SET quantity = REPLACE( quantity, 0, 1 );
```

It is changing all values that contain a 0 to 1, so even quantities that have 90 are changing to 91, I am looking to change ONLY the fields with values of 0s. This should be relatively straightforward  but I cant find much online or here that answers this specific question

Comment: You mean starting with 0?Show same sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

UPDATE oc_product_option_value SET quantity = 1 WHERE quantity = 0;